# DsGetDcName failing for Domain Controller

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, domaincontroller

I have added two additional Windows Server 2012 domain controllers to my domain. When running dcdiag /v I receive a failure:

Doing primary tests

Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\NEWDC
Starting test: Advertising
Warning: DsGetDcName returned information for
\SVR.mydomain.local, when we were trying to reach NEWDC.
SERVER IS NOT RESPONDING or IS NOT CONSIDERED SUITABLE.
......................... NEWDC failed test Advertising

It seems odd that the server "NEWDC" returns information for our original primary DC "SVR".  Any ideas where to start troubleshooting?

Ran dcdiag /v  and errors above noted.

Ran repladmin /showrepl  and it shows successful replication.